# Docusign- RestAPI and how to handle clients with SSO enabled

Tags: docusignapi

My company (C1) has DocuSign implementation feature set up with RestApi and we use oAuth to authenticate users with email and password to create and send envelopes. This functionality works perfect.
One of our clients said they have SSO enabled in their org and would like to SSO directly to DocuSign from my company page instead of providing password option. In our current implementation, users are prompted for email address first and then the password.

If clients have SSO enabled, I assume they go directly to Docusign but to get that functionality, is there anything I need to do regarding changing the existing workflow or implementation for RestAPI.
Do we need to obtain consent for our Client (who has SSO enabled)?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do anything differently. These clients would be able to authenticate to your integration/app using SSO. If they are already autneticated, a cookie remembers it and they would automatically be redirected back to your app. The first time, the would have to give consent to your app to enable it to do things for them, but after that - smooth sailing, without any need to login or anything.

Feel free to let me know if you run into any issues. Otherwise, you'r good.

Comment: I had done testing with the client yesterday who had SSO enabled for DocuSign. It did not work as expected. Client put in the email address,  and they were redirected to the client's IAM for authentication. They had to input the username and password for authentication. Once they put in their details, the consent screen showed up, and they granted consent. They were redirected to DocuSign. Today morning client tried the same process,  they were sent for authentication. But this time the consent did not show up.  Why is redirection to the client's IAM authentication always happening?

Comment: the consent is only needed once (unless explicitly revoked).
As to your other question, you would have to ask their IT and IAM. DocuSign does not dictate or even control the rules about how often and under what conditions IDPs require users to authenticate.

Answer (score 0):

As Inbar says, if your application uses either the OAuth Authorization Code or OAuth Implicit grant flow, then your application will automatically support SSO once the user's DocuSign account has been set for SSO.

If your application uses the OAuth JWT grant, then SSO has no bearing on your application since your application is itself authenticating with DocuSign and impersonating a user.

And the above is why Authorization Code grant or Implicit grant is preferred over JWT grant whenever there's an option to not use JWT grant.

Comment: Thank you Larry and Inbar. I have a call on Tuesday with the client to test out their use case of SSO enabled on our system I will reply back here If things work all well. 
Thanks again for you help and support

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Legacy Header authentication, your application won't be able to authenticate as users who have SSO Login enforced. Until you're able to implement one of the OAuth workflows, users who need to use your API integration will need to have their Login Policy set to allow them to login with a password. More info on Login Policy is available here: https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-to-exclude-specific-users-from-SSO-requirements