# DocuSign -- Setup SSO for developer account only for testing SSO functionality

Tags: docusignapi

My company has DocuSign partnership and we have integrated REST Api's for our clients.
I had previously asked `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61420267/docusign-restapi-and-how-to-handle-clients-with-sso-enabled`. Unfortunately SSO is not working for our client when using my application. It's working for them when they use another application. They are planning to move to our platform as soon as this functionality of SSO works.
I wanted to know if there is a way to test, by enabling SSO in my developer account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. 
You would have to get a domain (something.something) that you registered and change the DNS record so that DocuSign knows you own it.
You would have to have an IDP (like Okta) configured to use your account and set it all up in DocuSign Admin.
Here is an article that explains how to do all of that:
https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/org-admin-guide-identity-providers